# External app Post to angular app from external app

Tags: angular, post

I have my UI client at angular application running at http:\abc and web apis are at http:\xyz. My client app communicate to apis for any data.
I have requirement to implement SSO, which means login at external app http:\123 and send SAML response to my application which is http:\abc.
Now problem is angular can't handle post requests.. i need to pass SAML request to http:\xyz. Is there any way i can pass post request through client(http:\abc)?

i have exact same issue as mention in this post: [External servers posting to angular 2 routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42153822/external-servers-posting-to-angular-2-routes)

Answer (score 0):

As the answer to the question that you referenced explains, an Angular application cannot accept a POST request from an external server, because it is a **client** application, running in the user's browser. It is **not** a web server.

Your web server is at http://xyz, and that is where the third party must post it's data.

Comment: Thanks.. yeah looks like i have to go that way..will see how to route to client from api   after authentication.